# Ocaml Conversion String to int to char

Tags: ocaml

I need to implement this function somewhere

```
String.get: string -> int -> char
```

I have tried this one but it does not seem to work

```
let String.get = fun x -> char_of_int(int_of_string x) ;;
```

The error I get is:

```
let String.get = fun x -> char_of_int(int_of_string x) ;;
           ^^^
Error: Syntax error
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.get` is a syntax to denote the function `get` in module `String`. The syntax can not be used to (re)define a function as you wrote.

The function is documented [here](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.02/htmlman/libref/String.html):

> `val get : string -> int -> char`
>
> `String.get s n` returns the character at index `n` in string `s`. You can also write `s.[n]` instead of `String.get s n`.
>
> Raise `Invalid_argument` if `n` not a valid index in `s`.

What you are trying to implement is different, you are trying to read, from the string, an integer, and then convert it to a digit char (?)

Depending on what your actual requirements are, you might be asked to reimplement `String.get` on your own, so for example you would pick a different name in your current module (for now, this is sufficient, you don't need to bother about modules):

```
let char_at s n = ...
```

Or maybe you do actually need to convert from an integer. Please clarify your question.